# Quantstrat logical error while running applySignals - missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, quantitative-finance, quantstrat

I am having this error while running a strategy back-testing in the R, using Quantstrat package. Whenever, I try to use applySignals function to test the signals, it shows the logical error. I tried to remove the NAs by na.omit(FB) command, but when you calculate Simple Moving Average, you will have the NAS in the beginning. Can somebody suggest me the solution?

Thanks,

```
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
require(quantstrat)
require(quantmod)
require(blotter)

initDate="2015-01-01"
from="2015-01-02"
to="2015-06-30"

options(width=100)

currency('USD')
Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")

symbols = c("SPY", "FB", "TWTR")

getSymbols(symbols, from=from, to=to, src="yahoo", adjust=TRUE) 
stock(symbols, currency="USD", multiplier=1)



suppressWarnings(rm("account.MAC","portfolio.MAC",pos=.blotter))
suppressWarnings(rm("order_book.MAC",pos=.strategy))


tradeSize <- 1000
initEq <- tradeSize

strategy.st <- portfolio.st <- account.st <- "MAC"
rm.strat(strategy.st)
initPortf(portfolio.st, symbols=symbols, initDate=initDate, currency='USD')
initAcct(account.st, portfolios=portfolio.st, initDate=initDate, currency='USD', initEq=initEq)
initOrders(portfolio.st, initDate=initDate)
strategy(strategy.st, store=TRUE)

#parameters


nFast = 10
nSlow = 30


#indicators

add.indicator(strategy.st, name="SMA",
              arguments=list(x=quote(Cl(mktdata)[,1]), n=nFast),
              label="nFast")

add.indicator(strategy.st, name="SMA",
              arguments=list(x=quote(Cl(mktdata)[,1]), n=nSlow),
              label="nSlow")

test <- applyIndicators(strategy.st, mktdata=Cl(FB))
head(test, 5)


#signals


add.signal(strategy.st, name="sigCrossover",
           arguments=list(columns=c("nFast", "nSlow"), relationship="gt"),
           label="longEntry")

add.signal(strategy.st, name="sigCrossover",
           arguments=list(columns=c("nFast", "nSlow"), relationship="lt"),
           label="longExit")

test2 <- applySignals(strategy.st, mktdata=Cl(FB))

Error: Error in if (length(j) == 0 || (length(j) == 1 && j == 0)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue with my code.

So, if I only use mktdata object instead of mktdata = Cl(FB), Quantstrat is working fine. I am not able to understand fully why it is working that way, but somehow it worked fine.

```
test2 <- applySignals(strategy.st, mktdata)
```

Comment: What is happening here is that you're unrolling the functionality of the applyStrategy function.  The `mktdata` object is available after you call applyIndicators.  Inside applyStrategy, it would be passed as the 'mktdata' argument to applySignals. You could also have passed mktdata=test into your applySignals call.